Save as tiff - 16bit unsigned
I receive 'integer 2 unsigned tiff' images from colleagues. They look fine in 'Paint' and in DM.  After data processing in DM, I have real images.  After taking care of the range, ConvertToShort() creates 'integer 2 signed' images. But any attempt on creating the correct tiff file (16bit unsigned) fails.
I am using ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument() followed by ImageDocumentSaveToFile() setting the tag groups "Save As Grey Scale", "Include Annotation" and "Save As Grey Scale" all to "1".  The resulting images look very different in DM versus Paint.
Example code:
void my_SaveAsTiff( image tbdat, string path)
{   //  Default values for Tif:  keep actual size and burn in annotations
    number saveGreyScale = 1    // Convert to grey scale
    number includeAnno = 1      // "burn in" annotations on the display 
    number fullScale = 1        // Use data size not display-size of image
    tagGroup tg = GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupGetOrCreateTagGroup( "Private:Save Display" )
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Save As Grey Scale" , saveGreyScale )
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Include Annotation" , includeAnno )
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Full Scale" , fullScale )
        
    imageDocument doc = tbdat.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
    doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( "TIFF Format", path, 1)        //  "0"... Save as shown - but full resolution (via 'includeAnno')
}   

string path = "C:/...................."

out = realImage("temp", 4, 2048, 768)   
out = 100 + 20.9*icol 
out.ConvertToShort()    //  
out.showImage()

my_SaveAsTiff( out, pathConcatenate(path, "temp"))

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Are you absolutely sure this is the DigitalMicograph scripting language?

I am absolutely sure

Then remember to include all your details: "After data processing in DM I have real images" doesn't really mean anything, what did you do, and what do you mean with "real images"? Similarly, what does "any attempt on creating the correct tiff file fails." mean? Fails how?

a)  "real images" ... of type real to be specific.
b)  the images saved as tiff files have very odd contrast.  I had hoped the example would help clarify

Gotcha. You'll want to add those details to your post rather than leaving them hiding in the comment. Do you have a better program to test with, like Photoshop, Irfanview, etc? (ms paint is not exactly a benchmark for TIFF files, especially not "standard" 24 bit colour TIFF).

To convert data to unsigned 16 bit (uint16) you can use
number uint16Type = ImageConstructDataType( "scalar", "uint", 0, 16 )
yourImage.ImageChangeDataType( uint16Type )

Alternatively, you can always create an image of correct size and data format and then just copy the data:
image conv := IntegerImage("temp",2,0,2048, 768)   
conv = yourImage


BmyGuest is the best !
